# Springdata pagination in a server-client application

Tags: java, rest, pagination, client-server, spring-data

I am having a hard time understanding how to retrieve the information in pages, rather than as a whole thing. My current application so far has a database, a server/service and a front-end GUI client app.

The backend (service) looks like this:

IOrdheadService.java

```
public interface IOrdheadService {

@GET
@Path("/ordheads")
@Produces("application/json")
List<Ordhead> getOrdheadList();

@GET
@Path("/ordhead/{id}")
@Produces("application/json")
Ordhead getOrdhead(@PathParam("id") String id);
```

OrdheadService.java

```
@Service
@Path("ordheadservice")
public class OrdheadService implements IOrdheadService {

@Autowired
private OrdheadRepository ordheadRepository;
@Autowired
private IPrimaryKeyGenerator primaryKeyGenerator;

@Override
public List<Ordhead> getOrdheadList() {
    return ordheadRepository.findAll();
}

@Override
public Ordhead getOrdhead(@QueryParam("id") String id) {
    return ordheadRepository.findByPrimaryKey(id);
}
```

OrdheadRepository.java

```
public interface OrdheadRepository extends JpaRepository<Ordhead, String> {

Ordhead findByPrimaryKey(String id);
}
```

And the client receives information like this:

```
    private List<Ordhead> resultList;
    resultList = client.getOrdheadList();
```

And then I iterate through the resultList using the |< << >> >| buttons on screen.

Attempting to replicate that functionality with pages, I tried the following in my OrdheadService

```
    PageRequest page1 = new PageRequest(
            0, 20, Direction.ASC, "primaryKey");
           Pageable p = new PageRequest(0, 20);
    return ordheadRepository.findAll(page1).getContent();
```

Which works - returns the first 20 results. However, I need for client to know how many pages there are. That way if there are 40 records and client is on record 20, pressing the >> button will get the next 20 records and move client to record 21.

I have tried to read the following links:

https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-rest/wiki/Paging-and-Sorting
http://blog.fawnanddoug.com/2012/05/pagination-with-spring-mvc-spring-data.html

but haven't figured out how to properly implement it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ordheadRepository.findAll(page1)` returns a [`Page<Ordhead>`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html) that contains all necessary information along with content of the page.

Comment: I didn't get a chance to test it out (actually run the code), but just by looking at the javadoc now and changing my line to `Page<Ordhead> page = new PageRequest(...)` - seems to give me all the methods I need to get the functionality. Thanks!